# How can i add texture correctly

Tags: texturing

I want to add texture to the one side of an item but in the uv mapping the texture direction is vertical but I want it horizontal how can I change the direction of texture?
How can edit uv mapping that texture pieces of item would connect together? [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Select the UV face in the UV Editor and rotate 90°? Or please show some screenshots or even share your file

Comment: Either rotate the face in the UV map in the _UV Editor_ or rotate the texture with a _Texture Coordinate_ and a _Mapping_ node in the _Shader Editor_.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I add the screenshot

Comment: Thanks but do the answers given in the comments work?